# Input type submit button in form css issue

Tags: html, css, forms

I have input type button (in a form) in a div, i tried changing the css of the input but it has no effect.

```
<input type=button value="Search" id="search">
```

css:

```
input[type=submit] {
color: #000000;
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: The type you have is submit in the css, but the type it is  is button in the html. Try changing the css to type=button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup specifies `[type=button]`, yet your CSS references `[type=submit]`.

Change your HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given button instead of submit [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/197rpebk/)

```css
input[type=submit] {
    color: green;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input type is `button` (without quotation marks). It should be `submit`. Also you CSS-selector should be with quotation marks.

```css
input[type="submit"] { ... }
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the id so just refence that:

```
#search {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolons in your css:

```
input[type="submit"] {
color: #000000;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size: 16px;
}
```

Or

```
input[type="button"] {
color: #000000;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css do:

```
input[type='button'] {
color: #000000;
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         font-size: 16px;
}
```

also try putting the button for the type param in quotes:

```
<input type='button' value="Search" id="search">
```